# How to remove a tag with regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I have such string:

```
<span class="cDkSuggestion"></span>
<var class="tSuggestionTag r5">representation</var>
<span class="ib p1 tSuggetionName">for<b>rep</b>resentation</span>
<var class="tSuggestionTag r5">for<b>rep</b>res...</var>
<var class="tSuggestionTag r5">cost of representation</var>
```

and regex

```
query = query.replace(/<var.*>(.*)<\/var>/gi, "");
```

result of this regex is

```
<span class="cDkSuggestion"></span>
```

I need

```
<span class="cDkSuggestion"></span>
<span class="ib p1 tSuggetionName">for<b>rep</b>resentation</span>
```

How to check in regex that  does not includes others tags in replacing?

Comment: You really shouldn't use regex to parse or remove html tags, maybe you should try to restate you question and explain the underlying problem you are having.

Answer (score 2):

You really should use a parser, but if you want a regex, make it not greedy:

```
/<var.*?>(.*?)<\/var>/gi
```

or, safer:

```
/<var[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/var>/gi
```

Comment: If he really wants to "not include other tags", this might be not enough : using [^<]* would be safer.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the text contains only  tags, you can use this:

String test = testString.replaceAll("(?i)]*>", "");

For example, if the input string were SomethingAnother Thing, then the above would result in SomethingAnother Thing.

In a situation where multiple tags are expected, we could do something like:

String test = testString.replaceAll("(?i)]*>", " ").replaceAll("\s+", " ").trim();